# Using a global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

How do I do this?

My code is something like this:

```
var number = null;

function playSong(artist, title, song, id)
{
    alert('old number was: ' + [number] + '');

    var number = '10';

    alert('' + [number] + '');
}
```

The first alert always returns 'old number was: ' and not 10. Shouldn't it return 10 on both alerts on the second function call?

Comment: Damn Ya'll! Thanks for all the answers so fast.

Comment: Why do you write 

    alert('old number was: '+[number]+'');

and not

    alert('old number was: '+number);

Because it will alert an array with one item inside, not the item (number)

Comment: Hmmm dunno but it works. I don't think it will look for any array because I conjoin empty space on the right side + ''; or maybe not I dunno.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using `var` when setting number = '10', you are declaring `number` as a local variable each time.  Try this:

```
var number = null;

function playSong(artist, title, song, id)
{
    alert('old number was: ' + [number] + '');

    number = '10';

    alert('' + [number] + '');
}
```

Comment: How do you then access that variable out site the function playSong and get the value 10?

Comment: @johnsnails The variable is declared outside the function, so when assign number=10 its actually the global variable is referred but if we use var number = '10' in side function then it will have local scope, we wont get the value 10 outside the function.

Answer (score 12):

Remove the `var` in front of `number` in your function.  You are creating a local variable by

```
var number = 10;
```

You just need

```
number = 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're declaring a new variable named `number` inside of the function.  This new variable hides the global `number` variable, so the line `number = 10` assigns only to this new local variable.

You need to remove the `var` keyword from `var number = 10`.

Answer (score 2):

Like in C, you need to define your variable outside of the function/method to make it global.

```
var number = 0;

function playSong(artist,title,song,id)
{
    alert('old number was: '+[number]+'');
    number = '10';
    alert(''+[number]+'');
}
```

Comment: It's reassuring to see the same answer posted within the same minute.

Comment: Actually, any definition without 'var' will be a global variable, regardless of where it's defined.  Javascript can be scary.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain in detail. To declare global variables and local variables in JavaScript

```
var firstNumber = 5; // Local variable
secondNumber = 10; // Global variable or window object
```

When your program is like this

```
var number = 1;
function playSong() {
    alert(number);
    var number = 2;
    alert(number);
}
```

As per the JavaScript compiler, all declarations/initializations of variables will move to the top. This concept is called [hoisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Scoping_and_hoisting).

As per the compiler, the program will execute like:

```
var number; // Declaration will move to top always in Javascript
number = 1;
function playSong() {
    var number;
    alert(number); // Output: undefined - This is a local variable inside the function
    number = 2;
    alert(number); // Output: 2
}
```

If you need to access the global variable inside the function, use *window.number*.

```
var number = 1;
function playSong() {
   var number = 2;
   alert(window.number); // Output: 1   - From a global variable
   alert(number); // Output: 2   - From local variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also access it in any function like `window.number`, after removing `var` inside the function.

Comment: That is probably true, but perhaps say something about the context (e.g., would it work in Node.js?).

Answer (score 0):

I’ve come across this answer in 2020 and after searching some more online I have found that apparently in the JavaScript definitions if you place variables outside of functions or even create a file called *globals.js* and just put all your globally required variables in that file, make that file the first user .js file in your script tags after jQuery and any other plugins you need, globals will load before your other scripts and allow you to call variables from *globals.js* within any script on the page.

[W3C JavaScript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

I have tested this theory within a [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) application that I am building and I have been able to call variables from the *globals.js* file within a page that is loaded via [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to a *jconfirm* dialog for a troubleshooting wizard to set up the return values for when the dialog is closed.