# how to define global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how I can define a global variable in javascript. 
That's what I am doing and I want currentValue to be global so everytime gotoNext and previous function can change its value

```
onPageClick : function(event) {
                var currentValue = event.target.innerHTML;

                if (currentValue == "Next")
                    this.gotoNext();

                if (currentValue == "previous")

                    this.gotoPrev();

            },

gotoNext : function() {
                this.currentValue +1;

            },

gotoPrevious : function() {
                this.currentValue -1;

            },
```

but currentValue is not defined in goToNext and gotoPrevious!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a global variable in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167202/using-a-global-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You're not really asking about a global variable, but a class level variable.

You need to set `this.currentValue = event.target.innerHTML;`

Comment: and where should I declare it? outside of function?

Comment: You don't need to declare it. Just setting `this.foo = 1;` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define currentValue outside of any function scope. Like this:

```
<script>
var currentValue = '';

/* YOUR SCRIPT GOES HERE */

</script>
```

But then, you must change your code on the two last functions:

```
gotoNext : function() {
                currentValue += 1;

            },

gotoPrevious : function() {
                currentValue -= 1;

            }
```

But be carefull with this, globale variables are a bad thing. IMO, the best way to define an object is as follow:

```
var yourObject = function(){
    var currentValue = '';

    var that = {
            onPageClick : function(event) {
                var currentValue = event.target.innerHTML;

                if (currentValue == "Next")
                    that.gotoNext();

                if (currentValue == "previous")

                    that.gotoPrevious();

            },

            gotoNext : function() {
                currentValue += 1;

            },

           gotoPrevious : function() {
                currentValue -= 1;

            }
       };

       return that;

};
```

And then, you use it like this:

```
var obj = yourObject();
obj.gotoNext();
obj.gotoPrevious();
```

I would advise you to learn about scope and closures :

http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Comment: Thanks you so much, actually there is an event: events : {"click a.a-page-item" : "onPageClick"}, when you click obPaecick function get called. but if I define it inside var yourObject = function(){ it deos not get called.

Comment: Could you please create a FiddleJS with your code, so I can help you ? Thx